# Oracle to MariaDB data migration

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, migration, mariadb

We are in the process of migrating a fairly large Oracle database (approx. 200 tables) to MariaDB. We used CA ERwin to help create the MariaDB schema objects, and are now trying to figure out the best way to migrate the data. For example, if I use SQL Developer's export utility, the resulting Insert statements are created with Oracle syntax, which can differ quite a bit from MariaDB's syntax. Rather than handling every set of Inserts on an individual basis, I'm hoping somebody has been through this before and can suggest an alternative.

We looked at the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard, but it doesn't directly support migration from Oracle to MariaDB/MySQL (no surprise as Oracle owns MySQL).

Has anybody come across a utility that will make this task easier and save time?  Thanks.

Comment: Google suggests [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mariadb)

Comment: Try a pre-Oracle copy of Workbench?

Comment: The SQLines data migration utility has worked very well for us.  It's a pretty sophisticated tool.